# How to create a dummy variable based on row numbers in R

Tags: r, variables

I have a 10 (question items) by 500 (respondents) vector in R.

Upper 250 are male while lower 250 are female.

Can you tell me how to create a gender variable, and assign 0 and 1 to this variable based on row numbers in R?

Thank you very much! Stay safe.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should provide a small sample of your data using `dput()` and show the code you have used.

Comment: Could you provide an example of input and an example of how your result should look like? This would help to answer the question (making it reproducible). You could use e.g. `dput` to create such an example.

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes your dataset is in a data frame, not a vector, that the dataset is named "dat" (change it to whatever you are calling your data), and that the variable "gender" does not already exist in "dat".

```
dat$gender <- NA # Creates a new, empty column in the dataset (NA stands for missing data, or not available)
dat[1:250, "gender"] <- "0" # assigns the category 0 to rows 1-250
dat[251:500, "gender"] <- "1" # assigns the category 1 to rows 251-500
```

Hope this helps! As the comments suggest, providing a sample of your data will help us help you.